# Can I have webpack emit the bundle to two directories?

Tags: javascript, json, bash, webpack, configuration

I have this configuration

```
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/dist');

// ... snip

output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: DIST_DIR
},
```

which works fine.

However I would also like to have bundle.js written to another path.  So it is emitted in 2 places.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put each entry's output in different sub-directory, you can add the path variable `[name]` to the filename. For example, if  you have two entries: *'bundleOne' and 'bundleTwo'*, and you want to put their output to the sub-directory './bundleOne' and './bundleTwo', you can use following configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  entries: {
    bundleOne: './bundleOne/index.js',
    bundleTwo: './bundleTwo/index.js'
  }

// ... skip

  output: {
    filename: '[name]/dist/[name].bundle.js',
    path: __dirname
  }
}
```